# Get the axes to extend further

Tags: graphics

I have the code

```
Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], GridLines -> Automatic, Axes -> True]
```

and I want the axes to extend out by five in all directions (and the gridlines to extend along with them), but they conform to the length of the arrow. Is there any way to change that?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding e.g. `PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}` within your `Graphics`.

Comment: @MarcoB, that works beautifully, I just figured out it'd be `PlotRange->{{-5,5},{-5,5}}` - thanks so much! If you answer I'll accept it.

Comment: A shorthand for @Marco's suggestion is `PlotRange -> 5`, which automatically does the extension in four directions.

Comment: @J.M., thank you! I used that and it works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way is to add `PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}`:

```
Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[J. M.'s shorter notation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127741/get-the-axes-to-extend-farther#comment345516_127741) is `PlotRange -> 5`:

```
Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> 5]
```

[image]